# how to synthesize audio in iPhone

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I need to synthesize a voice so that it can be used to speak the text that is supplied to it. how can it be done in iPhone. I went through Sphinx voice synthesizer and other voice synthesizers, but they have some predefined voice for converting text to speech. In my app I require the voice provided by me to respond back.

Any suggestions in this regarding where to start with, is very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for the same thing. It looks that apple doesn't provide any library for that, despite the fact the iPhone uses for speech during auto-text. The only way I have found till now is using 3rd party http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone. I havent tested yet.